# How do I convert this text to a panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, file, dataframe

I have a file without a csv format, and the content is this.

File:

```
"TITULO: Albedo SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ===Trees===
Because forests generally have a low albedo, (the majority of the ultraviolet and [[visible 
`spectrum]] is absorbed through [[photosynthesis]])
"

"TITULO: Albedo SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ===Human activities===
Human activities (e.g., deforestation, farming, and urbanization) change the albedo of various areas 
around 
"TITULO: Abraham Lincoln SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ==U.S. House of Representatives, 1847–1849==
[[File:Abraham Lincoln by Nicholas Shepherd, 1846-crop.jpg|thumb|upright|alt=Middle 
True to his record, Lincoln professed to friends in 1861 to be ""an old line Whig,
"TITULO: Abraham Lincoln SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ===Re-election===
{{Main|1864 United States presidential election}}
[[File:ElectoralCollege1864.svg|thumb|upright=1.3|alt=Map of the 
"TITULO: Algeria SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ===Research and alternative energy sources===
Algeria has invested an estimated 100 billion dinars towards developing research facilities and 
paying researchers. 
Ecological anthropology is defined as the ""study of [[cultural adaptation]]s to environments""
"TITULO: Agricultural science SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ==Fields or related disciplines==
{{Col-begin}}
{{Col-break}}
* [[Agricultural biotechnology]]
* [[Agricultural chemistry]]
* [[Agricultural diversification]]
* [[Agricultural education]]
* [[Agricultural economics]]
* [[Agricultural engineering]]
```

I have this program

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('datos_titulos.csv', header = None)
print(data)
```

I have this error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 3
```

And the dataframe table has to be

```
Tile                   Head                          TXT
Albedo                 Trees                         Because forests generally have a low  ...([[photosynthesis]])
Albedo                 Human activities              Human activities (e.g., de...areas around 
Abraham Lincoln        U.S. House of..1849           [[File:Abraham Lincoln by... line Whig,
.
.
.
Agricultural science  Fields or related disciplines  {{Col-begin}} {{Col-break}}...* [[Agricultural engineering]]
```

That is, 
the column title is titulo.
head is  párrafo y subtitulo      == this text ==
txt is text to the next title.

Comment: Could you use multiple find to find one end for title, another find for subtitle and paragraph? Or is it better regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use two sets of regular expressions with the re.module, first we will iterate over your text file to get the title and head fields.

secondly, we will use a `re.split` to gather the text field, this is based on the assumption that although your data is in a messy text format, it's still maintains some order Title > Header > Text.

You'll have to do some further cleaning of the `Text` column, but that's all part of the fun :)

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

pandas_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:

      pat = r"TITULO: (.*) SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ===(.*?)==="
      if re.search(pat, line):
          pandas_dict["title"].append(re.search(pat, line).group(1))
          pandas_dict["head"].append(re.search(pat, line).group(2))


with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    body = f.read()

    b = re.split(r"===", body.strip())

    for line in b[2::2]:
        pandas_dict["text"].append(line.strip())

df = pd.DataFrame(pandas_dict)
```

---

```
print(df)

             title                                     head                                               text
0           Albedo                                    Trees  Because forests generally have a low albedo, (...
1           Albedo                         Human activities  Human activities (e.g., deforestation, farming...
2  Abraham Lincoln                              Re-election  {{Main|1864 United States presidential electio...
3          Algeria  Research and alternative energy sources  Algeria has invested an estimated 100 billion ...
```

---

```
print(df[df['Title'] == 'Algeria']['Text'])

paying researchers.
Ecological anthropology is defined as the ""study of [[cultural adaptation]]s to environments""
"TITULO: Agricultural science SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ==Fields or related disciplines==
{{Col-begin}}
{{Col-break}}
* [[Agricultural biotechnology]]
* [[Agricultural chemistry]]
* [[Agricultural diversification]]
* [[Agricultural education]]
* [[Agricultural economics]]
* [[Agricultural engineering]]"
```

Comment: I have a run this program but in the dataframe row 21 and row 23 is mistake. 21 Demographics of Angola [[Total fertility rate]] :6.09 children born/woman (2018 est.) Country ...
22 Alberta 21st century [[File:East Village Calgary Flood 2013.jpg|thu...
23 Albert Einstein = World War II and the Manhattan Project =\n{{See also|Einsteinâ€“SzilÃ¡rd letter}}

Comment: @ProSyth can you link your txt file ?